Unable To Store Cookie With react-auth-kit
I've been trying to create a React website that allows you to log in, but I've been having issues getting the react-auth-kit to work with my code. I've been able to successfully obtain a token and then use the signIn function, but it's not storing the cookie in the web browser.
Here is the code I'm using to log in:
console.log('Sending request to FastAPI server...');
const response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.21:8000/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
});

if (!response.ok) {
  throw new Error('Invalid credentials');
}

const data = await response.json();
console.log('Received response:', data);

const token = data?.token;
if (!token) {
  throw new Error('Token is undefined');
}

const signInParams = {
  auth: {
    token: token,
    type: 'Bearer',
  },
  refresh: data?.refreshToken, // Assuming your backend provides a refresh token
  userState: { email: email, name: email },
};

console.log('Signing in with params:', signInParams);

if (signIn(signInParams)) {
  console.log('Successfully signed in!');
  push('/dashboard');
} else {
  throw new Error('Failed to sign in');
}
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Error:', err.message);
  setError('Invalid credentials');
}

I've already wrapped my whole page with a provider. Below is the code for that.
import React from 'react';
import createStore from 'react-auth-kit/createStore';
import AuthProvider from 'react-auth-kit/AuthProvider';
import { UserData } from '@/types';

const store = createStore<UserData>({
  authName: '_auth',
  authType: 'cookie',
  cookieDomain: '192.168.1.21:3000',
  cookieSecure: false,
  debug: true,
});

const Providers = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider store={store}>
      {children}
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

export default Providers;

I then have a page that I would like to password protect with the import NextAuth from '@auth-kit/next'; imported and set up.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried removing and updating them and re-writing the code, but none of that makes it store the cookie, which then makes it think I'm not logged in. I am new to React, so I might be missing something simple.

Basically if the JWT token doesn't have an expiry then it will be removed as soon as it is saved as react auth kit assumes it's already expired.
https://github.com/react-auth-kit/react-auth-kit/issues/1653
https://github.com/react-auth-kit/react-auth-kit/issues/1653#issuecomment-2041654024

You are aware of the need for the commenting privilege, which you do not have. You know the rule ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). In that situation, please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism, an answering post, for what it is not meant for and which you are not yet allowed to do.

However, you are so close to an actual answer according to [answer], that I would like you to [edit] and make more obvious (and directly here, not linked) what the solution is which you propose. Because apart from "though shalt not misuse answer posts for commenting" there is also the "though shalt not only link to solutions" (see the [tour]). Give it a try please.
